Unable to reference classes in my .NET MAUI unit test project
I have a .NET MAUI project that I'm trying to write unit tests for but I'm unable to reference any classes from within my unit test class. I've added a reference to the project that contains the classes I'm trying to test. Not sure but I think it might be relevant that my .NET MAUI project is targeting multiple platforms. I don't believe it has any references to any UI elements.
I've tried both NUnit and XUnit but I see the same result (doesn't recognize the class I'm trying to instantiate).

You can also check this doc: UI testing.

You can refer to the following steps to do unit testing:

Create a xUnit Test Project and add the maui project that you want to test to Dependencies
Add these codes in your .csproj of mauiapp:

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0;net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
    ...


   <OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net8.0'">Exe</OutputType>
   <OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0'">Library</OutputType>

Then you can do unit testing for your maui project.
